# change Stack Panel position inside canvas dynamically?

Tags: wpf

I have 4 StackPanels inside the canvas. Now, I want to arrange it's position up and down dynamically.
I am finding lots of information on Google, but we can't get any idea how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You may set the `Left` and `Top` attached properties by means of the [SetLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft.aspx) and [SetTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop.aspx)
 methods:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(stackPanel, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(stackPanel, 50);
```